seeking suggestions for visualizing relationships between extracted topics and ratings in R
I have a set of product online reviews data. The dataset contains review text and 1-5 star ratings.
I've extracted 5 prevalence topics using R stm package. They are price, design, packaging, promotion strategies, and varieties. I also divided reviews into three sentiment groups based on the star ratings: 1- and 2-star ratings were classified as "negative", 3-star ratings were "neutral", and 4- and 5-star ratings were "positive".
Now I would like to graphically present topical prevalence across sentiment groups. That is for example, a graph showing that the topic "price" is largely associated with "negative" sentiment while "design" is positively discussed.
Any suggestions for this task?
Edit: Is it possible to present the data like the graphic below (extracted from the paper: stm: R Package for Structural Topic Models)


How about keeping the original 5 ratings and using a stacked bar chart with a diverging color palette?

Try looking into radius charts, star charts, and certain types of cobweb diagrams such as described in the Oxford Dictionary of Statistics or at https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anubhav-Pratap-Singh/publication/345128547/figure/fig10/AS:973671535497221@1609152792879/Cobweb-diagram-of-five-sensory-attributes-of-REV-dried-broccoli-orange-and-carrot-over.ppm

@rolando2 suggestion is good! Will try. Ps. I have edited the question and make it clearer for what I would like the result to be like.
